# Defining new class through method with block

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I have a function which defines and returns a new class, with some pre-built methods.  E.g.:

```
def define_class(name, options={}, &block)
  klass = Class.new(Class) do

    def say_hello
      puts "Hello!"
    end

    def say_goodbye
      puts "Adios!"
    end
  end

  parent_class.const_set(form_class, klass)
  klass
end
```

So, for example, this works:

```
define_class("testing").new.say_hello   #=> "Hello!"
```

But I would like to be able to pass in custom methods through a block, which would then be added to my class, like so:

```
define_class "testing" do
  # ... custom methods
end
```

Such that this would work:

```
klass = define_class "testing" do
  def interject
    puts "Excuse me?"
  end
end
klass.new.interject #=> "Excuse me?"
```

I can't figure out how to make that work though; I've tried instance_eval, class_eval, and yield, and none are producing the desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try simply:

```
def define_class(name, options={}, &block)
  klass = Class.new(&block)

  parent_class.const_set(form_class, klass)
  klass
end
```

If you want to call the block *and* your own block, you should use `class_eval`:

```
def define_class(name, options={}, &block)
  klass = Class.new do

    def say_hello
      puts "Hello!"
    end

    def say_goodbye
      puts "Adios!"
    end

    class_eval(&block)
  end

  parent_class.const_set(form_class, klass)
  klass
end
```

Comment: Uri - Where I run into problems with that is that I need not just the defined functions in the block, but also the other pre-defined functions (e.g. `def say_hello`).  How can I get both to work together?

Comment: try using your code, and then calling `class_eval(&block)` in your block

Comment: Ah, that worked!  I'd tried it before, but forgot to pass in the blcok with the '&' sign, and kept getting type errors!